# django-facebookconnect extended permissions

Tags: django, facebook

I am wanting to add some extended permissions to django-facebookconnect namely "email". After looking through the code I see that the actual connect is managed in javascript. So, I thought that something like this might work

```
{% load facebook_tags %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function() {
        FB.Facebook.init("{{ facebook_api_key }}", "{% url facebook_xd_receiver %}"{%extended_permissions%});
    });

    function facebookConnect(loginForm) {
        FB.Connect.requireSession();
        FB.Facebook.get_sessionState().waitUntilReady(function(){loginForm.submit();});
    }
    function pushToFacebookFeed(data){
        if(data['success']){
            var template_data = data['template_data'];
            var template_bundle_id = data['template_bundle_id'];
            feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,function(){});
        } else {
            alert(data['errors']);
        }
    }
    function pushToFacebookFeedAndRedirect(data){
        if(data['success']){
            var template_data = data['template_data'];
            var template_bundle_id = data['template_bundle_id'];
            feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,function(){window.location.href=template_data['url'];});
        } else {
            alert(data['errors']);
        }
    }
    function pushToFacebookFeedAndReload(data){
        if(data['success']){
            var template_data = data['template_data'];
            var template_bundle_id = data['template_bundle_id'];
            feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,function(){window.location.reload();});
        } else {
            alert(data['errors']);
        }
    }
    function feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,callback) {
        FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(
            template_bundle_id,
            template_data,
            null, null, null,
            FB.RequireConnect.promptConnect,
            callback
        );
    }
</script>
```

here is the extended_permissions tag

```
@register.simple_tag
def extended_permissions():
    if hasattr(settings,'FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS'):
        return """, {permsToRequestOnConnect: "%s"}""" % ','.join(settings.FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS)
    return ''
```

In theory I think the above code should work. Actually it does work it just breaks the popup window functionality. When the user accepts the request from the app they are redirected(within the popup) to the home page. Before the edits the popup would close and the main browser window would be redirected to /facebook/setup.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So this is your template, but what does it actually output?

Comment: this is from the js.html template from the django-facebookconnect app which is rendered in the head tag of the base template. It is adding the required permission as expected. Which in this case is email

Comment: I looked through the documentation and found that I can pass an object with a "permsToRequestOnConnect" key in FB.init. Which should do exactly what I am wanting. The only problem is that it seems to break the code that closes the popup window when the user accepts the request.

Comment: Can you list the FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS string that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be here:

`FB.Facebook.init("{{ facebook_api_key }}", "{% url facebook_xd_receiver %}"{%extended_permissions%});`

I bet it should be

`FB.Facebook.init("{{ facebook_api_key }}", "{% url facebook_xd_receiver %}{%extended_permissions%}");`

or possibly even

`FB.Facebook.init("{{ facebook_api_key }}", "{% url facebook_xd_receiver %}?perms={%extended_permissions%}");`

Not sure, but I never liked the js api anyways. If you're still running into problems, try my Django oauth implementation: https://github.com/dickeytk/django_facebook_oauth